# 4 input logic gate, but all inputs not present in final formula

Tags: logic, digital, circuit

I need to draw a logic circuit using this K map.. but how can I represent all the other inputs on the circuit? I get (not)B as the answer.. but how should I show A C and D in the circuit?
[image]

Comment: follow the link for the Image description

Comment: Try not to link to third party sites but rather just upload the picture on the post

Comment: as I have a low profile it automatically 'linked' my image :-(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I eliminate inputs in a logic circuit design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22354226/should-i-eliminate-inputs-in-a-logic-circuit-design)

Answer (score 0):

You can either just place them in and have an open ended wire connected to nothing, or just don't include them. They have no relevance to the output of the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Since the K-Map brings the circuit into simplest form, its irrelevant where A, C, and D go. The K-map shows that, regardless of these variables, the simplest result will always be ~B. So, just put them as open wires or don't even include them. Doesn't really matter